# Reload table after removing row from firebase

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

In my application i created a table with all the data from a firebase object. When I remove a row from the table i need to refresh the page manually, is there a possibility to do this automatically? Same problem when i add an object to the database, if i want to see it i need to refresh the page.

This is the function in the service where i get all treatments:

```
  receiveTreatment(){
      this.treatmentsRef = this.db.list('/treatments');
      this.treatments$ = this.treatmentsRef.valueChanges();
      this.treatments$.subscribe(res=> this.allTreatments = res);
      console.log(this.allTreatments);
      return this.allTreatments;
  }
```

This is my add and delete function in the service:

```
  addTreatment(data){
    console.log(data[0].desc);
    this.generateId();
    this.db.object('/treatments/' + this.uniqueId).set({
      id: this.uniqueId,
      desc: data[0].desc,
      cost: data[0].cost,
      btw: data[0].btw,
      sub: data[0].category,
      time: data[0].time
    });
  }

  deleteTreatment(id){
    this.db.object('/treatments/'+ id).remove();
  }
```

The component looks like:

```
  constructor(private db: AngularFireDatabase, public settings: SettingsService) { 

  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.products = this.settings.receiveTreatment();
    console.log(this.products);

  }

  deleteTreatment(id){
    console.log(id);
    this.settings.deleteTreatment(id);
  }
```

And this is the table that is rendered:

```
<table style="width:100%">
                    <tr>
                      <th>Behandeling</th>
                      <th>Kosten</th>
                      <th>Btw</th> 
                      <th>Tijd</th>
                      <th>Categorie</th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr *ngFor="let product of products">
                      <td>{{product.desc}}</td>
                      <td>{{product.cost}} euro</td>
                      <td>{{product.btw}} %</td>
                      <td>{{product.time}} minuten</td>
                      <td>{{product.sub}} </td>
                      <td><a (click)="deleteTreatment(product.id)">verwijder</a></td>
                    </tr>

                  </table>
```

So when i add an object or delete one it need to update the table directly.

Comment: Usually the UI should auto-refresh if you use `db.list()` to populate it. The code you shared doesn't show how you populate the table, so it'll be had to say how to get it to repopulate when the data changes.

Comment: I have comment it below so you can take a look, I tought it should populate itself but that's not working. Can you see what i'm doing wrong?

Comment: Add the additional information in your question by clicking the edit link under it. Don't add it as a separate answer as that confuses the system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just fixed the problem. In the service i changed the receive function from this:

```
  receiveTreatment(){
      this.treatmentsRef = this.db.list('/treatments');
      this.treatments$ = this.treatmentsRef.valueChanges();
      this.treatments$.subscribe(res=> this.allTreatments = res);
      console.log(this.allTreatments);
      return this.allTreatments;
  }
```

to this:

```
  receiveTreatment(){
      this.treatmentsRef = this.db.list('/treatments');
      this.treatments$ = this.treatmentsRef.valueChanges();

      return this.treatments$;
  }
```

After that i subscribe the treaments$ in the constructor of the component like:

```
  constructor(private db: AngularFireDatabase, public settings: SettingsService) { 
    this.settings.receiveTreatment().subscribe( res => {this.products = res});
  }
```

Now it's real time updateing my table.

Answer (score 0):

write a function which will get all rows data.

```
getRowsData()
{
//write logics here to get
}
```

In the delete method, you need to recall the `getRowsData()`

```
deleteTreatment(id){
    this.db.object('/treatments/'+ id).remove();
    this.getRowsData()
  }
```

It will refresh the table data.